# Wordpress post thumbnail url is not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have an issue with my website built on wordpress.

I'm trying to display the post thumbnail into my blog's page but it's not working as expected...

Here it is :

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 9) );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $thumbnail = get_field( 'thumbnail' );
                $category = get_the_category();
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                            <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style=" background-image:url(<?php echo $thumbnail['url']; ?>);">
                                <div class="article-head">
                                    <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?><br><span><?php echo the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span></h2>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </a>
                <?php
                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

So here it is... I'm using ACF (advanced custom field) plugin to add an image field that i called "thumbnail".

```
<?php echo $thumbnail['url']; ?>
```

this is supposed to give me the thumbnail url... But all i get is the current page url which is http://robeen.ca/blog/. I don't understand why...

Can you guys help me with that ?

Comment: `get_field` shouldn't return an array except if you're using a repeater. Dump `$thumbnail` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_field()` returns Object (array of data), URL (string), or ID (int). It can be changed in field settings. `var_dump()` your return value to see what's inside.

[See docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) for details.

Comment: Yes, as you can see, i use "$thumbnail['url'] which means i'm getting the url from the array picture...